# How can I decide on which Firebase functions should be client-side or server-side?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm working on a project using react-native and Firebase as my backend.
Users can

- create posts
- leave likes
- leave comments
- follow other users.

Posts come in the form of text and images.

Basically, I need to perform C.R.U.D operations on each of them.
Now, I've heard that you should assume that all the code you deploy can be modified by a determined individual. So, with security in mind, **how do I best determine which CRUD functions should be client-side or server-side?**

Initially, I had everything as client-side functions. But then I switched everything over to cloud functions. But now I'm confused because cloud functions bypass Security Rules, so I really don't know what to do.

Is it overkill to make everything a cloud function? If functions related to the backend require props to be passed e.g., getting the number of likes of a comment by passing in commendID, should they be server-side functions? 
I'm looking for very **specific** answers e.g.,

> Create and Update for posts should be server-side and everything else should be client-side.

Comment: What you're asking is a matter of opinion, which is off topic for Stack Overflow. Without knowing the specific requirements and technical details of your software, it's really not possible to know what's "best".  The best solution might just be the one you're most comfortable with.  If you want others opinions on what's best, try posting on a discussion forum that allows for opinionated responses, such as Reddit.

Comment: Did you write a good blog post about this at some point, Doug? Not sure if it was this one: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-combine-rules-with-cloud-functions-for-more-flexibility-d03cdc975f50 --- Update, ah no... here it is: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c